# Add inputfield and connect to Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Need help to add a inputfield in the HTML so that the value from that inputfield is added in the 4th column in my sheet.

The function works excellent, I just need to add one more point of data when I press the button.

**JavaScript:**

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getLoc(value) {
    var SpreadSheetKey = "1NDDhHomd4uJ8Xc2OlmK_jtShCKRLuHrwMBieURtM8zo";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKey);
    var respSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var data = respSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var headers = data[0];
    //var numColumns = headers.length ;
    var numResponses = data.length;
    var c = value[0];
    var d = value[1];
    var e = c + "," + d; {
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 2).setValue(e);
        var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
        f = response.results[0].formatted_address;
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 3).setValue(f);

    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>

   <script>
      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
      }
      function showPosition(position) {
       var a= position.coords.latitude;
       var b= position.coords.longitude;
       var c=[a,b]
       getPos(c)
       function getPos(value) {
       google.script.run.getLoc(value);
       }
      }
   </script>
   
   <body>
      <h2>Thank you!</h2>
      <p> Your registration is complete. Have a great day! </p>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1wheniE0HFtA37frkolHfmnjRLFbNkTI3" alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:100px;height:120px;">
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to create an html `input` element and pass its value on button click as a second parameter to the Apps Script function

Sample:

*Code.gs*

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getLoc(value, inp) {
    var SpreadSheetKey = "1NDDhHomd4uJ8Xc2OlmK_jtShCKRLuHrwMBieURtM8zo";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKey);
    var respSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var data = respSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var headers = data[0];
    //var numColumns = headers.length ;
    var numResponses = data.length;
    var c = value[0];
    var d = value[1];
    var e = c + "," + d; {
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 2).setValue(e);
        var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
        f = response.results[0].formatted_address;
        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 3).setValue(f);


        respSheet.getRange(numResponses + 1, 4).setValue(inp);

    }
}
```

*Index.html*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <input type="text" id="myInput"> <br><br>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>

   <script>
      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
      }
      function showPosition(position) {
       var a= position.coords.latitude;
       var b= position.coords.longitude;
       var c=[a,b]
       getPos(c);
       function getPos(value) {
         var inp = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
         google.script.run.getLoc(value, inp);
       }
      }
   </script>
   
   <body>
      <h2>Thank you!</h2>
      <p> Your registration is complete. Have a great day! </p>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1wheniE0HFtA37frkolHfmnjRLFbNkTI3" alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:100px;height:120px;">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is awesome! What a great community! Thanks ziganotschka!